# I can not understand how to interpret the documentation on the Dart SDK mirrors library

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

In declaration of class `"DeclarationMirror"` I found these documentation about the `"owner"` property.

```
For a `parameter`, `local variable` or `local function` the owner is
the immediately enclosing function.
```

I cannot understand how interpret this information because I cannot find documentation about **how to reflect the following declarations** through Dart mirrors library.

1. `Local variable`
2. `Local function`

How should I interpret these `terms` applied to practical usage of this library?

1. Notice about the declarations that must be necessarily implemented in future but, for several reasons, currently not implemented.
2. Information unreliable and can not be perceived as documentation.

I more interested in item #1.

If this is a real documentation but not a unreliable information then where I can find information on which based these documentation?

That is, where is information about described in documentation `local variables` and `local functions` **mirrored declarations**?

```
I am about how to reflect them from their owners.
```

I hope that I quite correctly asked  question about the official documentation, given its purpose.

If there exist another way to describe this I'll be glad to hear it.

P.S.
This question asked on that reason that there is no other available information found in official documentation.

P.S.

Sample of code:

```dart
var clazz = reflectClass(MyClass);
var method = clazz.declarations[#myMethod];
// How to reflect mentioned in documentation local variable?
var localVariable = method.declarations[#myLocalVariable];
```

The sample of code is just an example, but official documentation is more similar to the law. It must clearly be interpreted.

Comment: This seems to be more a "complaint about documentation" rather than a SO type "how do I" question.

Comment: Before programming (or using some unknown features) I often read the documentation. This question is about how to achieve the effect of which is described in the documentation. Of course, in a practical way through writing code. So it's a question about how to programming in Dart language according to the its documentation. Although it is possible, in some cases, writing code without reading the documentation and not ask questions about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I see this:

The immediately enclosing function is indeed the owner of the local variables and local functions.
But that doesn't include that you can get hold of them by reflection.

I tried to assign a local function to a field of the class and tried then to get hold of the function using reflection. I got the field but don't know how to get the value the field references to (the local func)
Maybe this is possible but I couldn't find how.
If this would work the owner would probably be the enclosing function.

AFAIR there was a discussion somewhere that it is currently not possible to access local members using reflection but I'm not very sure about this.
I also think I saw somewhere that you can get the source of a function as text if that is of any use...

Comment: This is a far shot but I could not understand from your question what you wan't to do but can't or what exactly you want to know.
Maybe you can provide a code example and tell what you can access through reflection and what not.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. You say you can't find the documentation. And then you say you want to reflect about.... That are two different things. I can gues that you wan't the first to be able to do the second. But if someone here can provide an example you probably don't need the first. But I'm not sure about this because you are mezoni ;-). I think it would be helpful if you just provide a sample of the code you want to reflect about.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. Please confirm. You want to get variables or functions declared inside myMethod?

Comment: 1. Your new response that you edited completely not fits your first option. 2. Sorry, but your "Maybe this is possible but I couldn't find how" not help me for understanding documentation and its haziness.

Comment: That may be. But I think I helped at least that others can better understand your question and maybe someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: When you have answered me the first time, before I started for you highlight text in bold, you really think that I do not know basic things (local variables and others) about which you were trying to tell me?

Comment: No of course not. But your writing style is very confusing for me and I just tried to disambiguate the basics before discussing the more difficult stuff. In fact I think that in this discussions I can learn more from you than the other way around.